# Generating a uniform distribution (inverse-transformation)

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, inverse-transform

Assume that I can generate samples from a continuous random variable Y with an invertible cdf FY. I wonder what is the distribution of FY (Y ) (capital Y both inside and outside)?

My primary guess is a uniform distribution, but I'm not sure how to validate my answer.

Comment: Apply the usual change of variables formula. If you turn the crank, does a uniform density fall out? If it doesn't, think about how to characterize the density or cumulative density of a unifromly distributed variable and see if the distribution of interest has those characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common homework problem so I think an outline of the approach is called for.

Let F be the cdf of Y.

Let U = F(Y).

Now calculate the cdf of U:  P(U <= u)

Substitute in a function of Y, get that in terms of P(Y <= something) and recognize that P(Y <= something) can be written as F(something) then simplify and recognize the cdf of U (or take the cdf back to a density).

The detailed derivation is given at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform#Proof) but it's much better to do it yourself by hand as above -- you'll actually have a chance to remember it when you need it.